# How to configure dhcp range when starting Ubuntu hotspot

Tags: network-manager, dhcp, ubuntu-mate, hot-spot

When I start my hotspot in Ubuntu , it always set up network with range 10.42.0.0/24 , is there any way to change network or DHCP configuration ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What are the exact steps you took to set up the hotspot?

Comment: i just went to network manager and have used option create new wirelles network

Comment: Go [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and post the output on http://paste.ubuntu.com then [edit] your answer and post the link there.  Then leave another comment and I'll have a more in-depth look.